# cannot put Bootstrap icon not working in selectbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, select

When I use `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i>` it works well.

But if I try it in Html SelectBox it does not work.

```
<select title="Select your spell" class="selectpicker" data-show-icon="true">
    <option><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i>select</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i>1</option>
    <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-leaf'></i>">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Has there been any example given in bootstrap site for this? If not then you cannot achieve this straightly. You should be using any jquery libraries for this like **select2**.

Comment: I think nested HTML tag like `<option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-leaf'></i>">2</option>` does not valid. At least you cannot do that with default `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper, because there's no way to set `<option>` tag attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use select2 jquery library like @Guruprasad has mentioned, or you can use this https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

It has several options for displaying icons or other HTML markup in the select.

```
<select id="mySelect" data-show-icon="true">
  <option data-content="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery'></i>">-</option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-leaf'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-music'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-send'></i>"></option>
  <option data-subtext="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></i>"></option>
</select>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/l6ClKGBmLS

Answer (score 1):

The standard dropdown list helper does not support that, either you can write your own custom helper or use simple Html like below.

```
<style>
select#dropdown option[value="1"]   { background-image: '';   }
select#dropdown option[value="2"]   { background-image: '';   }
select#dropdown option[value="3"]   { background-image: '';   }
</style> 

<select id="dropdown">

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This link will help to write your own custom helper

https://forums.asp.net/t/2130842.aspx?How+to+create+a+Dropdown+menu+with+image+icons+using+razor+